# How will i use sed shell script for replacing a pattern in a list of file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I have some 100 files which have my name in it, `RAHUL`. I want it replaced with another term `RAHUL2`. I have a file which contains the list of files and i want to fetch it in a sed to do the changes.

files :

```
C:/desktop/file1.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file1.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file3.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file4.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file6.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file8.txt
C:/desktop/rahul/file9.txt
```

and in each file data, i want to replace all occurance of term `RAHUL` with `RAHUL2`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using some `Cygwin` environment on Windows, since you have `sed`. Then you can use `find` to list all the files and execute `sed` on them:

```
find C:/desktop -type f -name 'file*.txt' -exec sed -i 's/RAHUL/RAHUL2/g' {} \;
```

Please make a backup of the original files if you are using `sed -i` but aren't sure if the command is working already. This because `sed -i` will overwrite the original file. You have been warned.

Answer (score 0):

hek2mgl's answer is good if you want to search for all files matching `file*.txt` pattern on your `C:/desktop` directory.

Now as you already have a file containing the list of files to edit, here is another way to proceed:

```
while read FILE ; do sed -i 's/RAHUL/RAHUL2/g' $FILE ; done < files_to_edit.txt
```

The `read` command will read your input one line after another. Input is `files_to_edit.txt` file, as indicated by the `<` input redirection operator.

Remark about `-i` option remains valid: it will edit your files in place, so make backup, or at least run it first on a couple of files (potentially without `-i` option, just to check what output is).